# Bootstrap "navbar-fixed-top" causing issues with Blueimp photo gallery in fullscreen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox, blueimp, bootstrap-lightbox

After adding a "navbar-fixed-top" class to my Bootstrap nav and then clicking on a photo in the Blueimp lightbox gallery, the navbar is not hidden underneath it. It appears overlaid *on top* of the lightbox in fullscreen. This will cause the problem:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

The below code functions as expected with the navbar being obscured underneath the lightbox overlay:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

Note that this is *only happening on Chrome*. Image gallery in Firefox and Safari are both functioning as normal with the fixed nav bar enabled.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? It's driving me nuts and no amount of troubleshooting has produced any solution. Thanks in advance.

[my site](http://blacksquaretattoo.crg.io)

[blueimp gallery documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Can you show us a live example of your website? It's really hard to figure out anything with mixed up PHP files.

Comment: Apologies (stackoverflow noob here). Site is here: http://blacksquaretattoo.crg.io/

Comment: You mean the `.navbar-fixed-top` causes the navbar to overlap when viewing images fullscreen?

Comment: Correct. I just re-uploaded the site with .navbar-fixed-top added to the nav bar and as you'll see when you click an image in any of the artist photo galleries, the navbar is overlaid on the image lightbox. Again, this is only happening in Chrome for me.

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS: `.navbar-fixed-top { z-index: 1; }`.

Comment: Try changing the `z-index` value until it doesn't overlap anymore.

Comment: Have you tested it in Opera because the same issue is happening there (at least for me). Probably a Webkit issue, maybe concerning vendor prefixes.

Comment: I've played around with the z-index on both the nav and the gallery, but so far it hasn't had any effect on the overlay.

Comment: @vanburenx I've also confirmed that it is displaying incorrectly in Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a conflict when you combine and minify your **animate.css** with **blueimps css**.

Removing the animate portion of your css let the modal overlay the `fixed navbar`.

Comment: that was it! Thank you so much. Out of curiosity, how did you narrow it down to the animate.css conflict? I would have never guessed.

Comment: I made a duplicate of of a page from your site and once I saw the file structure that stood out.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. Cheers!

Comment: It's no problem and you're welcome! And please  mark your question as answered so it's removed from the queue and others can benefit from it.